# How to find the minimum time taken to eat at least P apple ? Please Help me to optimize the code for this problem

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-search

**Hi please help me with optimized solution for this question. I am also attaching a potential solution below. I need help to optimize the code in java. The question is given below .**

**Question :**

> Varun's team participated in an eating competition at FoodContest in
> which they are asked to eat at least P apples. Varun's team consists
> of N members where a member i (1 <= i <= N ) takes Arr[i] minutes to
> eat a single apple. the task is to find the minimum time to eat
> at least P apples.
>
> Note: A member can eat a apple any number of times.

**Example**

> **Sample Input:-**
> n=4, p=10 ,
> Arr[i] = {1 ,2 ,3 ,4}
>
> Sample output: 6
>
> **Explanation:-**
>
> 1st member will eat 6 apple , (ie, 1*6)
>
> 2nd member will eat 3 apple ,  (2*3)
>
> 3rd member will eat 2 apple , (3*2)
>
> 4th member will eat 1 apple , (4*1)
>
> total = 12 ( total > p ) ie, team need atlest 6 min (minimum) to eat atleast 10 apples.
>
> **Sample Input:-**
> n=7 ,p=7 ,
> Arr[i] = { 1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1 ,1 }
>
> Sample Output: 1

**Constraints:-**

> 1 <= N <= 10^5
>
> 1 <= Arr[i] <= 10
>
> 1 <= P <= 10^12

**Code:**  (note: I need help to optimize this code also reduce Time Complexity )

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 


class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] str = br.readLine().split(" ");    
        String[] input = br.readLine().split(" "); 

        int n = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);  
        long p = Long.parseLong(str[1]);  
        long [] arr = new long [n];

        long max = 1000000000000L ;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        {
            arr[i] = Long.parseLong(input[i]); 
        }
        
        
        for(long j=1;j<=max;j++){
            long sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                long rem=j/arr[i];
                sum=sum+rem;
                if(sum>=p){
                    System.out.println(j);
                    return;
                } 
            }  
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So ... have >>you<< tried optimizing the solution (using that hint)?  What problem did you experience?  Was there a bug or something?  Do you not understand what binary search is?  This strikes me as a "Can you help me" / request for assistance rather than a genuine question.  Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: thanks Stephen for commenting.  . thanks for pointing out error in question . there is no bug in this question only problem is time complexity will be high with my solution . so i need your help to optimise it .  the reason why i pointed out binary search beacuse one of my friend said we can optimise with binary search but i didnt get his point. if you have any potential optimised solution for my code please comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say input is `arr = {1, 2, 3, 4}, p = 60`.

Start by *calculating* the [least common denominator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_denominator) (LCD), which in this case is `12`.

Now calculate, for each minute in a 12 minute period, how many apples will be eaten:

| Time | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Member 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| Member 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
| Member 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
| Member 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| Total | 0 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 9 | 12 | 13 | 16 | 18 | 20 | 21 | 25 |

Create an array with the value from the last row, i.e. *calculate* this array:

```java
int[] total = { 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 18, 20, 21, 25 };
```

You don't need to store the intermediate per-member values. They are just shown above for clarity.

We now know that the team eats 25 apples per 12 minute period, so to eat a total of 60 apples, we need at least 2 full rounds. So we *calculate*:

```java
full rounds = p / 25 = 60 / 25 = 2
apples left = p % 25 = 60 % 25 = 10
time taken = 2 * 12 = 24 minutes
apples eaten = 2 * 25 = 50
```

Now do a *binary search* of the calculated array for the remaining apples, choosing the next higher value if an exact match is not found. For the 10 apples remaining, that would be `time = 6, total = 12`.

Which means we need another 6 minutes to eat another 12 apples, for a total of 62 (50 + 12) apples eaten in 30 (24 + 6) minutes.

***Result:*** 30 minutes.

Now good luck writing the code for this algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for giving an insight how to approach this question